# Comparative analysis topics for research in computer science

Tags: computer-vision, computer-science, cpu-architecture

I am given a task to do comparative research on any computer science topic, Can anybody help me out with the good topics. 
For example: Comparative analysis on different operating systems, i have to read the existing research papers and then make a research paper of my own at a bachelors level, comparative analysis topics related to computer science?

Comment: This is both too broad a topic to discuss in a Q&A format, and is also out of scope for SO since you're asking for a recommendation. Please do some research and come back when you have a focused question.

Answer (score 0):

The Computer Science field is so big you can go in any direction . first choose your direction Database, data structure, Software Engineering, Artificial Intelligence , Computer Graphics Operating System, etc. then there will be a Question on which topic

Comment: Just a theoratical research, Related to software engineering, im not going in implementation, thats not my level,

Comment: OK now we have a question now move forward in which area Requirement, Analysis, Design, Implementation, Testing,

Comment: Implementation or design

Comment: there will some coding related topic i think you should try for Requirement. Different Requirement gathering techniques or you can study on Software Cost Analysis.
in Design there are different Design techniques and you have Different Software Model like Water Fall model Incremental model etc you can compare them and pick the best one on the bases of your examples and study

Comment: Bro suggest me a generic topic... Like i mentioned comparing operating systems... Im already studying course of Software requirement engineering and software quality assurance

Comment: you said Software Engineering i gave you that

Comment: Software models are most generic

Comment: mythical Man month by Fred Brooks .. there are lots of interesting topic